# Getting RuntimeException while initializing Object

Tags: java, serversocket

I am trying to send an object from a Serversocket to an other Socket.
Whilst doing it the class where my Serversocket is defined in is creating Objects which it send via a `DataOutputStream`. 
But sometimes i am running into an exception after the Serversocket wasn´t sending Objects, despite a steady `Ping` with the `ObjectOutputStream` every 5 seconds, for quite some time.

The Serversocket and the Socket beeing connected are both running on the same computer.

The problems also seems to occur randomly since most of the time i am not facing this problem. Only around 1/10 after having the socket doing nothing for some time this exception is raised.

Is there anything i could do to recover this "corrupt cache entry"?

I´ve already seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262870/java-lang-runtimeexception-error-failed-to-recover-corrupt-cache-entry) but since i have just cleared my java cache and restarted my computer i am not quite sure if the cause is same.

the java Version:

```
JRE-Version 1.8.0_73-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
```

The code causing the Problems:

```
private ObjectOutputStream os;
...
protected void sendReportObject(int arch_id, String origin_server_path,
                             String origin_server_file_name, String destination_path,
                             String destination_file_name, String reportName, String repParam) {
    if(isOpen) { // is true
        try {
            System.out.println("SENDING THE FOLLOWING OBJECT");
            System.out.println("arch_id: " + arch_id);
            System.out.println("origin_server_path: " + origin_server_path);
            System.out.println("origin_server_file_name: " + origin_server_file_name);
            System.out.println("destination_path: " + destination_path);
            System.out.println("destination_file_name: " + destination_file_name);
            System.out.println("reportName: " + reportName);
            System.out.println("repParam: " + repParam);
            // The line causing the exception is the initialization of the Object Archive_Report
            Archive_Report rep = new Archive_Report(arch_id, origin_server_path, origin_server_file_name, destination_path, destination_file_name, reportName, repParam);
            System.out.println("Writing report: " + rep);
            os.writeObject(rep);
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

The Stacktrace with prints

```
arch_id: 521
origin_server_path: C:\path
origin_server_file_name: Report_User_12345
destination_path: D:\Path
destination_file_name: Report_12345
reportName: Report
repParam: A
FRM-92091: unexpected fatal error in client-side Java code
Java Exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR: Failed to recover corrupt cache entry
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.recover(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.getJarSigningData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile.getSigningData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile.getCodeSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheJarAccessImpl.getCodeSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ChildElement.checkResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at applet.connecter.ApplicationServerSocket.sendReportObject(ApplicationServerSocket.java:313)
    at applet.connecter.ApplicationServerSocketBean.setProperty(ApplicationServerSocketBean.java:67)
    at oracle.forms.handler.ComponentItem.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.handler.JavaContainer.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.handler.UICommon.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onUpdateHandler(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processSet(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessageReal(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processEventEnd(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.LWComponent.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.LWComponent.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I would check whether you have network problems and whether you have the latest version of Java in case this is a bug which has been fixed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey edited the question. I am using a fairly new java version. Also the two sockets communicating to each other are both running on the same pc, so network problems shouldn´t influence them?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262870/java-lang-runtimeexception-error-failed-to-recover-corrupt-cache-entry

Comment: This appears to be caused by an incompatible change in the cache and clearing it should fix the problem according to this http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=a7cf63c84c90ffffffffcfb0f434b5d0e5a?bug_id=6898702